# Ideal meta description length

Tags: google-search, search-results, meta-tags, title, meta-description

One source claims that a meta description for a website should be between 160 and 300 characters however when I do a test of 160 characters in seobility's SERP snippet generator, it thinks my text uses too many pixels for it to display properly in google search.

Just to clarify things, I made a 64 character title and a 160 character meta description, and the tool thinks I'm using 1256 out of an available 1000 pixel space which suggests that google will cut some of the text off. I attached a screenshot of the results:

[image: results]

So what should I aim for with the length of the meta description?

I feel if I use one too short, I won't rank well but I don't want my meta description to be cut off in the search engine results.

Answer (score 1):

The exact length isnt that critical. Because mono spaced font isnt used, the number of characters is an approximation.

Let Google index it and see your listing in search by using

```
Site:domain-name
```

Then adjust it if you want.

Comment: Also Google only uses the meta description in the search results about 10% of the time.  Most of the time, Google picks a snippet out of the page for the description.  Years ago, the meta description was used 100% of the time if it existed, but there is now no way to make that happen.